# Правильный путь

Tags: веб-программирование, функциональное-программирование, сетевое-программирование

Ребятушки, у меня такой вопрос: я думаю стать программистом, но я не могу понять хочу ли я стать им (я как бы хочу, но стоит ли это того). Пожалуйста скажите стоит ли становиться программистом? Почему?
(я просто взвешу + и - по вашим комментам и сделаю вывод)
//Я знаю, что многие скажут:"Вопрос не по теме!", - но, я считаю, что из всех ЯП, архитектур, протоколов ответ на этот вопрос надо знать в первую очередь

Comment: Может не стоит?

Comment: "но я не могу понять хочу ли я" - если вы не можете понять что хотите, как мы сможем?

Comment: Думать и хотеть две разные вещи. Посмотри пару видео о программировании. Это далеко не самая веселая работа. Особенно дедлайн)))

Comment: Не иди в программисты. Иди в грузчики. Грузчик - парень работящий!

Comment: Стоит - если действительно хочешь! Не стоит - если сомневаешся! Так в любой профессии, впринципе.

Comment: */Я знаю, что многие скажут:"Вопрос не по теме!"* - не скажут, а просто закроют его

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Те из моих друзей, кому по работе приходится поднимать вещи тяжелее, чем ноутбук и чаще, чем два раза в неделю, однажды пользовались случаем и вставляли в разговор что-то типа: «Бро (это обязательно начиналось с „Бро“), ты не напрягаешься на работе. Вот я только что отработал 4700 часов в неделю, копая отвёрткой туннель под Мордором»
>
> В чём-то они правы. Мордор — отстой, а чтобы копать туннель, требуется, очевидно, куда больше физических усилий, чем чтобы нажимать на клавиши. Конечно, если ты не муравей. Но, в интересах дискуссии, давайте сойдёмся на том, что стресс и безумие — не очень полезные вещи, окей? Отлично! Добро пожаловать в программирование.

---

> В детстве в моей спальне был чулан. Он имел какую-то странную форму. С первого взгляда всё казалось нормальным, но когда ты заходил в него по своим делам, ты замечал, что в стене справа есть альков, который можно использовать как маленькую полку. Потом ты всматривался вглубь и замечал, что от задней стенки алькова уходит ответвление, создавая проход в абсолютную пустоту, куда не проникал ни один луч света. Ты моментально узнавал её — это то место, куда отступают все те голодные монстры, которых ты каждую ночь отгоняешь фонариками и плюшевыми игрушками.
>
> Вот это и есть изучение программирования. Ты изучаешь полезные инструменты, потом смотришь вокруг и видишь рядом какие-то новые полезные инструменты, и они показывают тебе ту бездонную пропасть ужаса, которая всегда будет рядом с твоей кроватью.

**Мы не психи по природе, но мы сошли с ума в процессе**

> Так что — нет, от меня не требуют поднимать объекты весом двадцать кило. Я поменял это на возможность стричь волосы у Сатаны в паху, пока он обедает содержимым моего черепа. И всё это ради того, чтобы пару кусочков интернета проработали ещё несколько дней.

Взято [отсюда](http://ruslanbes.com/blog/all/perevod-programmirovanie-otstoy/)

Comment: Красиво написано! :)))